# Export To Excel Fom DataGrid VB.Net Windows Application

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I need to Export DataGrids' Contents to Excel using VB.Net for a Window based Application.

How to do this.. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The are plenty of ways to do this. Create the excel file using static methods in the File class. Then you can create a OleDB connection to the excel file and then write all the data to it using SQL query.

Comment: This just blew my mind. I'm the idiot that uses the .net interop classes and writes the data out row by row, column by column. :(

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box DataGrid doesn't support this feature. You can 
a. Use a third party data grid that has this feature
b. Create a report that have the same contents as the grid. Report Viewer control that is freely available from Microsoft has the feature to export to Excel